# Apache Shiro integration and Netty ExecutionHandler/OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: multithreading, netty, shiro

I just added an `ExecutionHandler` to my server pipeline just before my main business logic handler as recommended in the documentation.

I am using Apache Shiro http://shiro.apache.org/ for security. It worked fine until I added the `ExecutionHandler`.

*The issue*: 
Shiro's execution context is bound to the current thread in which you obtain the `Subject` object. So, if the `Subject` is obtained in the worker thread, but the business logic executes in a separate `ExecutionHandler` managed thread then the two execution contexts won't be connected as far as Shiro is concerned. Thus Shiro in the `ExecutionHandler` thread will fail to be aware that the `Subject` is in fact authenticated. So I'm getting Authentication errors.

It is possible to associate a given `Subject` with a `Runnable` before passing it to `Executor.execute()` so that the security context is maintained. See: http://shiro.apache.org/subject.html

Based on this I think need to find a way to associate the current Shiro `Subject` with the `ExecutionHandler` `Runnable`.

I'm still trying to fully understand the `ExecutionHandler` and `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` implementations.

Basically I need to call `subject.associateWith(aRunnable)` just before `aRunnable` is passed to `Executor.execute(aRunnable)`.

Does anyone have thoughts on where/how I could hook Shiro into the mix?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Would be interesting to see how you integrated shiro and Netty. If it is opensource, could you share the link? Maybe paste it as a github gist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Shiro can automate the thread handoffs for you.

You should be able to just use one of the [SubjectAwareExecutor](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/concurrent/SubjectAwareExecutor.html), [SubjectAwareExecutorService](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/concurrent/SubjectAwareExecutorService.html), or [SubjectAwareScheduledExecutorService](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/concurrent/SubjectAwareScheduledExecutorService.html) implementations out of the box.  You can wrap the actual ExecutorService that will execute the Runnables, and you're good.  For example:

```
ExecutorService myExistingExecutorService = //get from somewhere
ExecutorService useThis = new SubjectAwareExecutorService(myExistingExecutorService);
```

You can 'inject' or configure the `useThis` instance anywhere in your application and the calling code doesn't ever need to know Shiro exists.

For example, an unaware component calling `useThis.submit(someRandomRunnable)` has no idea that Shiro is in use, but the Shiro Subject will still be retained across threads.  Check out the respective JavaDoc pages for more.

Comment: I've wired up the `SubjectAwareExecutorService` in my application context and everything works very well now. Many thanks for this. It's exactly what I was looking for. Cheers, Matt